# The effect of the shell command "cat -"

Tags: linux, shell

I am playing on [pwnable.kr](http://pwnable.kr/).

The command is:
`(ruby -e 'print PAYLOAD'; cat -) | nc SERVER PORT`

The PAYLOAD, SERVER and PORT are just placeholders because I don't want to be a spoiler.  This command should make a stack overflow on the server side and let it execute the `system("/bin/sh")`.

I know these commands' meaning but I don't know why I can't do it in this way: I use `nc SERVER PORT` first, and input the payload manully, press enter and input the command I wish to be executed on server side.

If I use the shell string, everything works fine but if I do it manually, I get the "****stack smashing detected****" error from server side.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It could be a timing issue. If you're typing `PLAYLOAD` directly into `nc`'s standard input, the server will receive the data much more slowly, probably in multiple calls to `read` (if the input contains newlines or the terminal is in raw mode). If you use Ruby to print `PLAYLOAD`, it'll probably be sent all in a single packet and the server will get it in a single call to `read`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat -` simply means to redirect the standard input of `cat` to its standard out. This seems pointless, but it forces the line to keep reading user input instead of just terminating `nc` as soon as the payload is sent.

Also, `ruby -e 'print PLAYLOAD'` extremely inefficient. Ruby never needs to be called (it will cause slower execution of the line), and also the command assumes that ruby is installed. Replace it with `printf %s 'PAYLOAD'`, which will work in most (if not all) shells.

Comment: Using `printf %s 'PAYLOAD'` would provide a mechanism *certain* to work in all POSIX-compliant shells. The POSIX spec for `echo` is... messy; there are a great many strings it leaves unspecified in terms of how they're emitted on output.

Comment: From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html: "If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a backslash ( '\' ) character, the results are implementation-defined." -- so you're off in implementation-defined territory from the offset; on a strictly XSI-conformant system, by contrast, `-n` is *explicitly forbidden* from being recognized as an option.

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy, I have updated my answer to show this.